# Python - Append to a Json file in a loop

Tags: python, json, bots

Good morning

Yesterday i started to write a simple announcment bot for cryptocurrency markets. 
At this point i would like to read the ticker (prices of a market) and save the data into .json file in real time. Python's `dump` function does the trick. So far the code looks like this

```
start = time.time()
while 1:
    end = time.time()
    raz = end - start
    if raz >= 5:
        for i in range(len(self.keys)):
             self.dictTicker(self.values[i])
             start = end
    sleep(0.005)
```

`self.dictTicker` is the function that goes through selected markets and saves data in .json file

```
def dictTicker(self, market):
    ticker = api.get_ticker(market)
    self.data['year'] = datetime.now().year
    self.data['month'] = datetime.now().month
    self.data['day'] = datetime.now().day
    self.data['hour'] = datetime.now().hour
    self.data['min'] = datetime.now().minute
    self.data['sec'] = datetime.now().second
    self.data['bid'] = ticker['result']['Bid']
    self.data['ask'] = ticker['result']['Ask']
    self.data['last'] = ticker['result']['Last']

    with open("{}.json".format(market), 'a') as f:
        json.dump([self.data], f)
        f.close()
```

An example of .json file then looks like this.

```
{"year": 2017, "month": 8, "day": 6, "hour": 6, "min": 38, "sec": 4, "bid": 0.00224, "ask": 0.00225999, "last": 0.00225999}{"year": 2017, "month": 8, "day": 6, "hour": 6, "min": 38, "sec": 9, "bid": 0.00223611, "ask": 0.00224, "last": 0.00224}
```

The problem is that this format `{}{}` is wrong. It should be `{{}{}}`. Or in other words list of dictionaries and not multiple dictionaries.

When i try to read the file i use the following code:

```
 with open("BTC-SEC.json") as f:
     a = json.load(f)
     print(a)
```

I get the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 121 (char 120)
```

I have searched on stack but i cant find the answer that would help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a side note `{{},{}}` is not a list of dictionaries (that's a dictionary of dictionaries), `[{},{}]` is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Append to a list, then always write the full list as JSON to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I figured out after some time that the trick is to have in fact a **list of dictionaries** so `[{},{}]`.
So it's just about creating an empty list before the loop and then `.extend()` it at each iteration.
Finally, outside the loop, the classic `json.dump(extended_list, file)` does a great job!
Hope it helped